# I get a low space warning on my chromebook install can i utilize or extend my root folder for more space? and how so? i have gparted installed

Tags: partitioning, gparted, chromebook

[[image]]

[image]

I did a full install with a live USB and mrchromebox firmware. I'm not that tech savvy and I know there are very similar questions here and I have read the answers and still need more specific help. Pics of my gparted window and some chromebook specs as well as ubuntu version are included.

Comment: NO! You cannot change a disk or it's partitions while ANY of the partitions is mounted, or used as swap. You'll have to boot your install medium in "Try Ubuntu" mode.

Comment: Thank you I was aware of that part. Although for some reason it will boot my live USB that I installed from but then its hanging for some reason which is another problem altogether . Either way when I can boot that live I'm still not sure on what to do in order to give myself any space

Comment: Based on the gparted screen you posted, your disk is actually nearly full, so there is nothing you can do with partitions to make more room. You must figure out what you can delete to free up space. 15G is not very much space for an install; thumb drives commonly have more now.

Comment: My old laptop batteries have died. It only works with power connected all the time & I have to reset clock as coin battery also is dead. I was about to trash it, but my good laptop also totally stopped. I have a full install on an SSD. My old laptop could boot to grub & then choose install on SSD. Other than a bit show when using swap as only 1.5GB of RAM, it worked well. Suggest getting an external SSD. https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2489307

Comment: @OrganicMarble so that's where I was confused because I installed from a thumb drive which was only 8gb itself. I was unaware that it would take up more room than on the thumb drive itself.

Comment: ehmm 15Gb should be enough for /. You might be better off finding out what filled the partition. /var/log or ~./xsession-errors` might be filling it up. Or maybe snaps (delete those for instance). If you add another 15Gb you just postpone the inevitable... it will fill up but twice as slow.

Comment: 16 GB is not enough for comfortably using Ubuntu. Use a big enough fast SD card or a USB drive (at least 64 GB), and use it as the internal storage for your Chromebook.